# how to get list of words from list of words whose starting 2 words are same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose my input list is :

```
["customer service skill","sales representative",
 "customer service","customer service experience"]
```

Output should be :

```
[["sales representative"],["customer service skill","customer service","customer service experience"]]
```

Is there any effective way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["customer service skill","sales representative","customer service","customer service experience"]
result = defaultdict(list)
for i in lst:
    result[tuple(i.split()[:2])].append(i)   #Key = starting two words
print(list(result.values()))
```

---

or using `dict.setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
lst = ["customer service skill","sales representative","customer service","customer service experience"]
result = {}
for i in lst:
    result.setdefault(tuple(i.split()[:2]), []).append(i)   #Key = starting two words
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[['customer service skill', 'customer service', 'customer service experience'], ['sales representative']]
```